# Android Peripheral Requires Pairing

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an Android app that acts as a BLE peripheral.

When I connect to it using another device it always requests pairing. How do I make it so that it won't require pairing?

I have a single service and single characteristic and the permission on it are just normal read and write. I am not requesting any encrypted version of those.

Answer (score 0):

Every device has mac address, connection is made by using mac addresss.

Connect to device and Save connected device  mac address in shread preference so every time it will connect to that save device only.

So it will not ask pairing every time.

If you want to  disconnect that device , in disconnect method clear mac address from shread preference.
I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are saying. I have implemented this peripheral on Android, but am connecting to it using an app called LightBlue on iOS that I don't have the source to. Where are you talking about saving the Mac address?